# Sending SMS using Twilio in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

I tried the demo application for Twilio in a console app and everything worked great. However, if I use the same code in my MVC 4 app, it doesn't send any SMS messages.

```
public ActionResult SendTestSms()
    {
        string AccountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountSid"];
        string AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthToken"];
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        IEnumerable<string> phones = new string[] { "123-456-7890", "+1234567890" };

        foreach (var phone in phones)
        {
            twilio.SendMessage("+1234567890", phone, string.Format("Test Message"));

        }
    }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does anything show in your Twillio logs? What does SendMessage() return?

Comment: The Twilio.SendMessage() function should return the HTTP response from the Web API. I'd suggest printing it out, or checking your Twilio logs (https://twilio.com/users/account/developer-tools/app-monitor) to see what errors occured.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I was getting nothing in my twilio logs at all. I figured out that my company's firewall does not allow the request to go out through a browser request, but it does allow it from a console app. I ran the exact same code at home and it worked perfectly. Time to go talk to IT.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Looks like this issue was the result of a firewall problem but wanted to answer the more general question for all the people who aren't OP and end up landing on Stack Overflow looking for how to send SMS in ASP.NET.

Using our [C# library](http://twilio.com/docs/csharp/install?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=oct2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) you can send SMS with this code:

```
    string AccountSid = "{{ account_sid }}";
    string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var message = twilio.SendMessage("+14158141829", "+15558675309", "Brooklyn is in the house!");

    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

If you want to dive into code for a full ASP.NET application built to send SMS I'd recommend [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/server-notifications/csharp/mvc?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=oct2015&utm_campaign=stackathon).